# Record timestamp when cell is copied

Tags: excel, vba

I know that i can record the timestamp when the cell value changes. However, i want to record the timestamp when the cell is copied.

As an example, if i copied a cell from "Column B" using "CTRL+C", i want the timestamp of that action to appear in the 5th Column after "Column B".

Is this applicable?

Comment: There is no event fired when you press control-C.

Comment: You mean that this not applicable?

Comment: by applicable, do you mean possible? You could try implementing something like `Application.OnKey Key, Procedure` but that gets really complex and there are a lot of problems with it.